# "our own developed" or "own developed"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I am not sure if I should use our
We use a combination of our own developed and existing programs.

> We use a combination of our own developed and existing programs.

OR

> We use a combination of own developed and existing programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't say **of own**. If you want to use **own**, you have to say **our own**.

But your sentence is ambiguous.

Does the adjective **own** modify just the **developed programs** or the whole phrase **developed and existing programs**? If you had developed some programs and had acquired other programs, it could easily modify both.

Other ways of phrasing the sentence to avoid this ambiguity might be:

> We use a combination of existing programs and those developed in-house

or, if you wanted to emphasise that all the programs belonged to you:

> We use a combination of proprietary existing programs and those developed in-house.

or

> We use a combination of (proprietary) existing programs and those developed by us/ourselves

Comment: To answer your question, "own" just  modify the developed program.

Comment: @qbq In that case I should opt for the first of my three suggestions.